# ASPNet.Core reading appsettings from referenced assemblies?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

We're building an ASPNet.Core microservice (HSMService) and we reference several assemblies from another ASPNet.Core project (HSM). The HSM assembly needs to read the `appsettings.json` file in the root of the HSMService to set some values.

In our unit tests of the HSM project, the `appsettings.json` file is located in the root of the test project and we are using 
`.SetPath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` to read the values.

It doesn't work when we reference the HSM assembly in the HSMService, it is trying to load from the `/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0` directory where the DLL is located.

Is it possible to load the `appsettings.json` file from the HSMService in the HSM assembly or should we move the setting of the values into the code of the HSMService? Where would I put this?

Comment: Can't you inject your configuration to your assembly/library and let the service load it at run-time?

Comment: You're probably doing it the wrong way. It's your HMService that's supposed to have the `appsettings.json` file, not the other way around.

Comment: If you want to have a global appsettings.json, you could use the relative path, to load it, or have the configurations in your environment-variables ( in Azure for example).

Comment: Or you have a absolute path, that is reachable in development(local) and in production mode (server). If you can set that path this is also an opportunity.

Comment: @FrankFajardo, can you explain further how to do this?

Comment: @silkfire, The assembly is what is loading it, it needs the settings from the file.

Comment: OK, we've decided to modify the Assembly to take a parameter in the constructor to point to the `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: @MB34, try reading this: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core - Using Options and configuration objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#using-options-and-configuration-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've decided to modify the Assembly to take a parameter in the constructor to point to the appsettings.json file

```
public class HSMController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    public string contentRootPath { get; set; }

    public HSMController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
    }

    [Route("/PingHSM")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse), 200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse), 500)]
    public IActionResult PingHSM()
    {
        IHSM hsm = HSMFactory.GetInstance(contentRootPath);
        return Ok(hsm.PingHSM());
    }
}
```

The constructor in the HSMFactory takes care of taking the contentRootPath and setting the Config variables.

```
public static IHSM GetInstance(string configPath)
{
    // for now, there's only one
    Type t = GetImplements(typeof(IHSM)).FirstOrDefault();
    ConstructorInfo ctor = t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });// assume empty constructor
    return ctor.Invoke(new object[] { configPath }) as IHSM;
}
```